# find the latest row if column value is same else row with max value of same column

Tags: mysql

**I need to fetch the record from below table if `state` col value is same for an account then fetch row which `date_time` value is max else which `state` is max**

> state max means: which number is max (like in Desc order) `state3` > `state2` > `state1`

**Table**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  | account   | Name          | state     | date_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 145552    | Salleh        | state2    | 2020-05-08T20:55:45Z
2   | 145552    | Salleh        | state3    | 2020-05-04T06:50:27Z
3   | 145552    | Salleh        | state1    | 2020-04-01T21:10:32Z
4   | 836001    | Sharifudeen   | state2    | 2020-05-14T01:10:40Z
5   | 836001    | Sharifudeen   | state3    | 2020-05-13T01:10:40Z
6   | 321032    | Amir          | state1    | 2020-05-14T01:10:40Z
7   | 321032    | Amir          | state1    | 2020-05-15T01:10:40Z
```

**Required Result from above table**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  | account   | Name          | state     | date_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | 145552    | Salleh        | state3    | 2020-05-04T06:50:27Z
5   | 836001    | Sharifudeen   | state3    | 2020-05-13T01:10:40Z
7   | 321032    | Amir          | state1    | 2020-05-15T01:10:40Z
```

**My Query: It's not giving me the required result as expected above based on described condition.**

**Condition:** *if state are same for an account then fetch row which date_time value is max else which state is max*

```
SELECT a.*
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT account, max(state) as state, MAX(date_time) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM accounts 
    GROUP BY account order by state,date_time desc) acc
ON a.account = acc.account
and a.state = acc.state 
group by a.account
```

*My query result*

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Id  | account   | Name          | state     | date_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | 145552    | Salleh        | state3    | 2020-05-04T06:50:27Z
5   | 836001    | Sharifudeen   | state3    | 2020-05-13T01:10:40Z
6   | 321032    | Amir          | state1    | 2020-05-14T01:10:40Z
```

*The above two rows are correct but the last one row for account 321032 is incorrect, it should be 7th id row.*

Please help me out with this.
Thanks

Comment: Specify MySQL version - this is critical for your task.

Comment: *My Query: It's not giving me the required result as expected above based on described condition.* Of course, you need 2 levels of nested subquery (for MySQL 5.x), the most inner selects maximal state, intermediate gets maximal date_time for this state, outer gets the whole record by selected state and date_time.

Comment: @Akina Mysql version is 5.7.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t3.*
FROM accounts t3
JOIN ( SELECT account, state, max(t2.date_time) as date_time
       FROM accounts t2
       JOIN ( SELECT account, max(state) as state
              FROM accounts t1
              GROUP BY account
            ) subquery1 USING (account, state)
       GROUP BY t2.account, t2.state
     ) subquery2 USING (account, state, date_time);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6abeb7a83f07aaf740ff9d289cd09b67)